# Locate a drop-down element using Xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, drop-down-menu, popup

```
<div id="ext-comp-1080" class=" ListView" style="height: auto;">
<div class="listitem clearfix ListView-select ">
     <div class="col span90"> Today</div>
</div>
<div class="listitem clearfix ">
<div class="listitem clearfix ">
<div class="listitem clearfix ">
<div class="listitem clearfix ">
<div class="listitem clearfix ">
<div class="listitem clearfix">
<div class="listitem clearfix">
</div>
```

("Today" - The text Element I am trying to click)

It is part of a drop-down menu, which is opened when I click a link. There is enough wait time between clicks but still webdriver doesn't locate this element!

Options tried with Xpath:

//div[contains(text(),"Today")] --> Not working

//*[contains(text(),"Today")] --> Not working

/html/body/div[8]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2] -->  Not working

I can see this element in firebug but selenium cannot ! What could be wrong?

Comment: Any `frame` or `iframe` elements on the page?

Comment: Yes, I found one iframe.

<iframe id="ext-gen566" class="ext-shim" frameborder="0" style="display: none; visibility: visible; z-index: 14998; left: 1332px; top: 281px; width: 81px; height: 34px;">
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
</iframe>